# Soilgrids250 clay, silt percentage in depth of 0-30!

Tags: soilgrids

the new SoilGrids data only gives clay, silt percentages in the few set intervals (0-15,15-30,30-60). I want to find for the range 0-30,can I apply weighted averaging here or should i use the old 2017 data which has percentages for each depth?

Comment: Since the thickness of both 0-15 and 15-30 are 15 then you don't need a weighted average- just an average. You can make a new variable using field calculator called "0-30", populate it with the average of the 2 fields provided and then use that.